# Is there a way to combine flex-start with center in css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I do `justify-content: center;` cards are centered, but it looks quite rough if there aren't an even number of cards. So, I did `justify-content: flex-start;` and now I need to center them while are aligned left, I don't want the negative space, is it possible to do so with flexbox?

```
<section>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</section>
    
section {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Want it like this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider grid:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.consider_grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 20px;
  row-gap: 10px;
}

.card {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="consider_grid">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm looking for a flexbox solution for the problem tho, but don't think there is one now